# How to get 2 different iiyama monitors' color settings alike

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, colors, brightness

I had an old 26" iiyama, as 2nd monitor which had his best time, so I ordered a new one. I'd love to have an identical monitor as my primary one, but unfortunately iiyama doesn't produce that model anymore (ProLite XB2779QS / PL2779Q). A couple of years ago it was the only model with 4K. I ordered this monitor as partner: ProLite XUB2792QSU-B1 (QHD)

I must say that I'm impressed by the image-quality so far! But the colors / brightness etc. are way out of sync. Can anyone tell me what's the best approach to get both monitors giving similar output? It's not that it has to be exactly the same, but a bit look a like would be nice :-)

Thanks a lot in advance guys / ladies!

Answer (score 1):

You may never get them to match absolutely perfectly - I have 2 almost identical 27" 1440p screens which I can match to 'close enough' but not perfect.

Really, the only way to get even that close is to buy a hardware colorimeter.
The more you spend, the better it will be - such is life. By about $250 USD you're going to get one worth having.
I know this because my first one cost 60 bucks, my second 120 & my 3rd... 250. The first two simply weren't up to the task, though both were better than I could do by eye.

You can try matching things by eye, but you really won't have a chance compared to buying the hardware. There are online resources to help you - this is just the first hit from Google http://www.lagom.nl/lcd-test/ [look for 'online screen calibration'] By all means try them first, but don't be surprised if you can't get close enough.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Tetsujin, but that wasn’t my question. Maybe I’ve formulated things wrong. I’m not looking for an exact match, and finding a match isn’t quitte the question. It’s more like: howto? with a tool, what settings to start with changing, hardware or software tuning etc.

Comment: With a colorimeter, the software that comes with it will do it all for you. Without, then you just have to fiddle with whatever you can access in your Graphics control panel &/or the screen's onboard controls.